# It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'name' to table_name without specifying a default

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have added a following field in my already existing model:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

But it is giving following prompt when applying migrations:

```
 It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'name' to table_name without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
    Please select a fix:
     1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
     2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
```

I cannot set it's attributes to blank=True, null=True as this field is must. I cannot set it's default value as the field has to be unique. I also deleted all the previous data from that table.
If I try to set it's default value in command prompt, it says plz select a valid option.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you probably have existing records, but this field is new and unique.

This is what I suggest to do:

1. Use `blank=True`, `null=True`
2. Fill the existing records with unique names using data migration or manually.
3. Remove `blank=True` and `null=True` in next migration

Comment: FYI: No need to set `blank=True`, in this case.

Comment: Ah yes that's !False. Thanks!

Comment: I deleted all the data from that table, but still gives the same error.

Comment: Then do the steps I described here.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'name' to table_name without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.

Solution:
Select option  1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column) for now and then go to your models and make these changes:
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
Note* : you must remove name(unique = True) because blank names will not be unique and for uniquiness use id as a primary key

Comment: If the field needs to be unique, it can't set all existing entries in the database with a default value. Please consider the OPs requirements for a helpful response to the question